# NSManagedObject: Value change affecting relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have currently the following data model:

> An `Entry` Object that has an attribute `startDate` and an Relationship to
>   one `Month` Object
>
> A `Month` object that keeps *n* `Entries` an has some other attributes

The month Relationship will be assigned on creation of the Entry Object depending on the startDate.

Now the following problems occurs:
The user can change the start date and this can affect the month relationship. Whats the correct way to update the relationship when the startDate changes.

Is `-(BOOL)validateStartDate:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)error` in the `NSManagedObject` the right place to do this?

If yes how can I get the other months available in the current context? I think fetching objects from context in an `NSManagedObject` is not a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no other way to do it. Just fetch all the months with no predicate, figure out which one you need and set the relationship, or if you can get exactly the month you need by setting the `NSFetchRequest`'s predicate, it would be even better.

Comment: So can I just pass an ´managedObjectContext´ to an ´NSManagedObject´?

Comment: Yes, I mean your method should look like: `-(BOOL)validateStartDate:(id *)ioValue inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context error:(NSError **)error`, and you can place this method into a Category on `Entry` class, otherwise it would be erased everytime you regenerate the class for that Entity

Comment: Okay it worked this way very good. In fact I forgot about the `managedObjectContext` Property of `NSManagedObject` so it's no problem to do it in the standard validation